# Positioning nodes on a scene to work for all screen sizes SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, aspect-ratio, skscene

I have tried everything and nothing seems to work for positioning nodes for a universal SpriteKit game. I currently use .AspectFill as my scaling ratio and I have tried making unnecessarily complex algorithms to fit nodes (e.g buttons, a title image, etc) for my main menu in my game into bounds or sub sections of the scene. I have even tried positioning things relative to the visible parts of the scene. e.g

```
 sprite.position = CGPoint(scene.size.width/2, scene.size.height/2 + scene.size.height * 0.4)
```

and yes this works for gameplay elements such as a player I have figured that this method is horribly unpredictable for positioning HUD and menu screen elements as buttons then tend to overlap because of dynamic sizing of sprites and/or unknown scaling of scene depending on user's device (If I get it perfectly positioned on iPhone it goes off of the screen on iPad and vice versa) e.g

```
sprite.size = CGSize(screen.size.width * 0.6, screen.size.width * 0.6)
```

I then went onto making an extension of SKSpriteNode so that it can resize itself depending on a given bounds (CGRect) and then I realised just how complex, messy and time consuming positioning one node on my scene was. I must have the complete wrong idea of positioning nodes in my scene or I am doing it wrong. Now you understand the context here are my questions:

- Should I hardcode the positions (I have heard that this isn't a great method but since SpriteKit does the scaling for you shouldn't it work) ?
- Or should I create a dynamic position depending on the aspect ratio of each device eg.

`if scene.size.width/scene.size.height >= 16/9 {
//Create position here for this device
} else if scene.size.width/scene.size.height >.... { etc etc`

This method also seems unnecessary but I could be wrong

OR

- Is the solution some other method that I am not aware of

I cannot be the only person with this problem and from doing research for hours and hours reading every single stackoverflow answer and webpage Google returns to me that might have my answer I still have not found a solution that works for my problem. This question has been asked plenty of times but obviously the answers do not match to my learning style and it needs to be explained in a different way so that I finally understand it and with the amount of apps on the app store surely someone has an easy solution to such a stressful problem that is causing me to feel unmotivated to make my app and that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: if you are using aspect fill then you do not need to do % based calculations here

Comment: Really? But the height of the scene on the iPad is 430 something and on iPhone 6S it is 532 which is the set scene height :/

Comment: so?  you are doing aspect fill, that means that the scene size gets preserved no matter what size the screen is

Comment: So hard coding positions and sizes would be best then? And just see what works for all devices? :D

Comment: doesnt have to be hard coded, but the values can be absolute.  If you do a scene size of 100x100 with aspect fill, that means on every device, your scene is 100x100.  What happens is the 100x100 get scaled to the furthest borders of your phone, so cropping will happen on the nearest borders

Comment: aspect fit is the opposite, it scales to the nearest borders, and gives you black bars on the furthest

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid but when you say absolute what  do you mean? But that you so much for your help as well this is the second time you have helped me and I am really grateful

Comment: if you say CGPoint(10,10), it always takes you point 10,10  It doesnt have to be hardcoded, it could be placed in a variable that changes its numbers.  You do not have to do CGPoint(10/scene.size.width,10/scene.size.height)

Comment: Really? So CGPoint(10/scene.size.width, ...) isn't needed?! That will save so much time, thank you!!

Comment: only time percentage based math is needed is if you were using .Fill scaling, because it doesn't preserve the aspect ratio (but does preserve size)  .ResizeFill is the only one that actually changes the size of scene, and since we are changing the size of the scene, you do not need to do percentage based math, otherwise you would use the .Fill scaling

Comment: Okay, thank you so much!!

Comment: actually, I got it backwards,  you do not need it with .Fill because the size is preserved, you do need it with .ResizeFill because the size is not preserved, and if you are doing .Fill and making new skscene with the screen size, then you are doing it wrong and should just be doing .ResizeFill

Comment: One more thing, how do you handle the bits that are cropped out for when you are making a HUD at the top of the screen in portrait mode?

Comment: What about .AspectFill though?

Comment: those you need to account for with math,  you need to figure out the padding needed

Comment: already explained aspectfill

Comment: Ahah okay sorry I didn't realise you were giving extra info about the other scaling settings, thanks!! Okay, so if I needed three labels for my HUD in the top of the screen I would make a padding for the top and sides and just with trial and error change the font sizing and padding values for them to be equally spaced for every device?

Comment: no, you can figure it out with math,  or you can search on here because I have posted the math to handle it, as I am sure others have, I just don't feel like looking for it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using AspectFill as your scaleMode, the scene automatically scales it. With this, you would then make the screen size 768x1024 (portrait) or 1024x768 (landscape). To make this compatible with all devices simply make the background 1024x1024 so it looks fine on iPad and you can adjust HUD elements for iPad only by doing something like this:

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
    yourButton.position.y += 100
    yourLabel.position.y += 100
    etc
 }
```

You don't need any complex algorithms and the scene looks great on all screens. I also suggest you change the anchorPoint of the screen to the middle so you position all the nodes from the middle rather than from the bottom left corner as this makes it much easier to centre things for all devices

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sensible route to go.

In your gameScene.didMoveTo(), do this:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
let screenScale = UIScreen.main.scale
   
self.size.width = screenSize.width * screenScale
self.size.height = screenSize.height * screenScale
    
self.scaleMode = .aspectFill
```

Yes, you can adjust the scene size dynamically, so that's what we do.

The screenScale is an adjustment for retina devices, it basically maps points (like CGPoint coordinates) to the physical pixels of the screen. Currently retina devices use a value of 2, but don't assume it will never change as new devices come out.

Now you can be sure, whatever device you are running on, that the scene size matches the view size.

The .aspectFill doesn't really do anything since the scene and it's view now match proportions exactly, but I guess it's best to set it to something.

What you now have is a scene that's exactly the same size at the physical screen, so positioning objects is very simple.

Assuming that you scene's origin is in the centre you can calculate, say, the top left corner position as:

```
CGPoint(x: -scene.size.width / 2, y: scene.size.height / 2)
```

But take care if you don't want stuff clipped by the notch or the rounded corners.

You may want to take a look at:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first.safeAreaInsets
```

Which will advise on how far to stay clear of notches etc.